# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Quartz.net over the windows scheduler?

Tags: .net, vba, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net, windows-task-scheduler

For daily tasks, such as

- converting csv files to excel files;
- creation of excel files (the contents of which are created using financial methods);
- moving and copying of files;
- calculation of daily financial and risk analysis metrics; and
- (this list will grow over time and will become more complex..)

Is Quartz.Net more suitable when compared to the windows scheduler? (Note: I am looking for advantages/disadvantages)

### Background

At present we currently have a number of Excel macro enabled workbooks that have been created to accomplish the above tasks. These at face value seem simple enough, however they each have their own set of complexities, which VBA (or should I say me) is just managing to achieve.

Since we are talking Excel, the obvious initial disadvantage for a switch to Quartz would be to convert all the VBA code to .Net (preferably C#, however VB.Net should be a quicker move, I think). However, *these tasks could also be converted to simple console apps that could run on the windows scheduler as well*.  To date, the current setup of using the Windows Scheduler works well with the Excel Macros.

I have recently stumbled upon Quartz.Net and wondered if this may be a long term option. The other main driving force behind this is that the above list of daily tasks will be growing and the way I see it is that maintenance of the Windows scheduler may become a bit of an issue especially with regards to access rights and job monitoring.

*In addition, a move from VBA to .Net is inevitable in any case, since the current setup allows for some users to tinker with VBA who then want to know what went wrong.*

My initial direction of thought leads me to think, that Quartz is the better option (skimmed though the tutorial). However, when coupled with the time taken for the above conversions, and the learning curve involved with Quartz, will I be delivering and adding tangible value to the business?

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe the limitations you are facing with your current setup? Personally, I try and avoid adding third party dependency where possible. You may want to look into moving your vba scripts from excel into WSH. This may give you the extra flexibility you need.

Comment: The third party dependency is key, its a library of financial quantitative functions. WSH can be used to a degree for some aspects, however this will exclude it from some of the benefits of using Quartz. The other aspect is that I am trying to limit the number of different technologies and move everything to .Net. Thus making long term maintenance easier IMO.

Comment: I was referring to quartz as the dependency. Can you describe some of the limitations you are trying to remedy?

Comment: the question is about Quartz vs Windows Scheduler. The limitations 1) "The other main driving force behind this is that the above list of daily tasks will be growing and the way I see it is that maintenance of the Windows scheduler may become a bit of an issue especially with regards to access rights and job monitoring." 2) "since the current setup allows for some users to tinker with VBA who then want to know what went wrong."